# having problem in implementing loops for sensor

Tags: java, android, loops

I am using an accelerometer, magnetometer and combined its data to get Azimuth, pitch, and roll. But I am only interested in pitch values.

```
 private Sensor mSensorAccelerometer;
private Sensor mSensorMagnetometer;
private TextView mTextSensorAzimuth;
private TextView mTextSensorPitch;
private TextView mTextSensorRoll;
private int count =0;
TextView liveCount;
private static final float VALUE_DRIFT = 0.05f;
float pitch;
private float[] mAccelerometerData = new float[3];
private float[] mMagnetometerData = new float[3];
```

My onCreate method:-

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    count = findViewById(R.id.count_textview);
    mTextSensorAzimuth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value_azimuth);
    mTextSensorPitch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value_pitch);
    mTextSensorRoll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value_roll);
    // Get accelerometer and magnetometer sensors from the sensor manager.
    // The getDefaultSensor() method returns null if the sensor
    // is not available on the device.
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(
            Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensorAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
            Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(
            Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
```

My onSensorChanged method is

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    int sensorType = sensorEvent.sensor.getType();
    switch (sensorType) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            mAccelerometerData = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mMagnetometerData = sensorEvent.values.clone();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    boolean rotationOK = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix,
            null, mAccelerometerData, mMagnetometerData);
    float[] orientationValues = new float[3];
    if (rotationOK) {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientationValues);
    }
    float azimuth = orientationValues[0];
    pitch = Math.abs(orientationValues[1]);     //pitch
    float roll = orientationValues[2];

    mTextSensorAzimuth.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.value_format, azimuth));
    mTextSensorPitch.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.value_format, pitch));
    mTextSensorRoll.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.value_format, roll));
```

Here I am only interested in pitch data.

```
if(pitch<0.70){
        count++;
        liveCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
```

The problem here is that if pitch<0.70 then increase the value of count by 1 but it increases the value even if the pitch is still <0.70. In simple terms, I want to execute it like "If pitch<0.70 the increasing count by 1 and then wait for the pitch to be > 0.70 after that again increase count by 1 if the pitch is <0.70 ".

Answer (score 0):

You should use a flag as an boolean to check if the pitch dropped below 0.70.

```
boolean pitchFlag = false;
if(pitch<0.70 && !pitchFlag){
   count++;
   liveCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
   pitchFlag = true;
}else if(pitch>=0.70){
   pitchFlag = false;
}
```